# No result from query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have made code without error for  connection and data fetching but i don't know why result for query is bool(false)

```
 <?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","xyz");
 echo "Connection made";

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

The code to query and execution is

```
<?php
include ("includes/connection.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM userdata ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Help needed here

Comment: Look at this line very carefully `$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","xyz");` then look at the rest of your code, notice anything different? Where you're also doing the same mistake; **mixing APIs** which do **not** mix. Look at this one also `$result=mysql_query($query);` --- [**Read the (F) manual**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Is there an error coming from the database?  Check `mysql_error()` for more information.  Also, "I have made code without error" is a pretty bold assumption given that your code is resulting in an error.  When you assume that your code must be perfect and that the compiler/interpreter must be broken, you're pretty much *always* wrong.

Comment: Your `echo "connection made";` is pretty much useless, since even if it wont connect it will echo that out. You are also mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions.. that doesnt work. pick one or the latter: go for `mysqli` if you dont want to use depracted functions

Answer (score 1):

You should use either mysql or mysqli. This is the main problem for the error

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","xyz") or die ("error in connection".mysqli_error($con);
?>
```

and use `$result= mysqli_query($con, $sql)` where $sql contains your query

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use mysql_* functions they are depracted use mysqli or pdo instead.
2. You need to fetch results of your query with fetch functions like mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_row() to get results of your query. There are plenty of examples in PHP manual.

In your cause it would be something like this:

```
  <?php
  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("didn't connect to db");
  mysql_select_db('name_of_your_db', $con);
  $query="SELECT * FROM `userdata` ";
  $result=mysql_query($query); //this returns resource ID that needs to be fetched

  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
     print_r($row);
```

If $result is false it means that query failed it can be caused by several issues for example there is no DB selected, there is no connection etc.

I'd also give you better solution with PDO

```
<?php

$dsn      = 'mysql:dbname=nameofyourdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user     = 'root';
$password = 'yourpass';

try
{
   $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM `userdata`") as $row)
            print_r($row);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Go over the question/code again, attentively. Plus, [`read my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386093/no-result-from-query-in-php#comment37715852_24386093) which will give you a clue, so you can rewrite your answer.

Comment: You mean that he mixes mysql and mysqli functions?

Comment: That is exactly it. OP should be using all `mysqli_` and so should your answer.

Comment: My answer is written with mysql_ functions not mysqli :)

Answer (score 0):

As i stated in the comments, your echo up there to tell you you connected to the mysql server is not effective. I pulled out an old function from me to show you how to do it and make it clear where the error is.

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');    
$db = mysql_select_db('xyz',$con);

function OpenConnection(){
    global $con;
    global $db;
    if (!$con){
        die('cannot connect to server!');
    }else{
        if(!$db){
            die('cannot connect to database!');
        }
    }
}
```

If you dont get anything back, you ll be good to go.

Comment: Doesn't it always. Like I said, old function. I dont use this stuff anymore, but still. It's an example.